# Could not use EXCEPTION in Postgresql procedure with explicit COMMIT

Tags: postgresql, exception, stored-procedures

I want to remove data from a big table, so I developed a procedure to delete 1000 rows once and then commit. Below are code example:

```
create table test1(id int not null);
INSERT INTO test1 (id)
SELECT id
FROM generate_series(1, 10000) AS id;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE clear_data_in_batches(delete_sql TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    rows_deleted INT;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- Execute dynamic SQL statement for deletion
        EXECUTE delete_sql;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS rows_deleted = ROW_COUNT;
            
        -- Exit loop if no rows were deleted
        IF rows_deleted = 0 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Rows deleted: %', rows_deleted;
        -- Commit the transaction after each batch
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_data_in_batches_wrapper()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    delete_sql TEXT;
BEGIN
    
    -- Define the DELETE SQL statement
    delete_sql := 'DELETE FROM test1
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM test1
            LIMIT 1000
        )';

    -- Call the delete_data_in_batches procedure with the delete_sql parameter
    CALL clear_data_in_batches(delete_sql);

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'An error occurred: %', SQLERRM;
END;
$$;
```

I called procedure delete_data_in_batches_wrapper in psql command line, and got below error

```
TDS=# call delete_data_in_batches_wrapper();
NOTICE:  Rows deleted: 1000
NOTICE:  An error occurred: invalid transaction termination
CALL
TDS=#
```

But if I remove

```
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'An error occurred: %', SQLERRM;
```

from procedure delete_data_in_batches_wrapper, the procedure works well.

Do you know the root cause and if there is any workaround for this problem?

Thank you.